# Flex: Display Color Coded XML?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, code-formatting

Is there a component anyone knows of that will take XML and display it has a color coded string so you can read it easily?

My app runs mostly from the dynamic XML that is loads. It would be great for debugging if I could click a button in the app to show me the XML it loaded in a readable format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this class: [SearchCoders/text](http://labs.searchcoders.com/text/) or when developing Air, this looks interesting too: http://www.air-tutorial.com/syntax-highlighting-in-flex-for-air

Comment: Awesome, my project just so happens to be an AIR project :)